# VB.net 4.5 .exe fails to execute when run via SSIS

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, windows, ssis

I have written a vb.net console program that links to a database and has a main function of producing report packs by joining together separate PDF pages in various configurations.

To do this I've had to use a few workarounds, but have tested the built and deployed app locally & manually which works fine. These are listed below:

I need the application to be called via SSIS so that it can be scheduled as part of a wider agent job.

I don't have remote access to the SSIS server that the job runs on, although can connect to it via SSMS / Trigger the job etc & can see a share of the folder in which the application .exe and associate files sit.

Because I don't have access to install applications on the server, I have taken the approach of installing the click once output from visual studio locally and extracting the .exe and associated files from the local apps folder. These files have then been copied onto the file share. Again I have tested that the .exe file can be run manually there whilst logged on using my credentials and this works no problem and produces the expected output files and the log file.

When the SSIS job runs, it uses a service account - I can't tell if the account has access to the shared drive for sure, but as it is able to move files on the drive for other jobs I assume this is true. Also I created a more basic console app which just reads the values from the XML file but doesn't write any output and it ran to success.

I've looked in SSMS and can see that the shared files are on the G: of the agent server. I assume that the .exe will also execute on the agent server so have tried mapping the file path to the G: and the file share. As I assume the securities will be different depending on how you approach the folder.

The add in required for creating the PDFs does not accept UNC file paths and so I need to give it a relative or mapped folder path. I can't map a drive because I don't know the agent account password - but can address this if absolutely necessary. Currently I load relative paths from the XML configuration file.

When the app is run manually on my own account from the shared folder location it creates the log file as expected.

When the app is run via SSIS the job fails with error code: -2146232576 and no log file is created.

As the log file is the first thing the app does I assume it is failing because it can't write an output.

Does anybody know of a way to confirm: 
A.) where the .exe is running (the package calls the .exe from the G: file path)
b.) What permissions the agent account has on the directory where it runs
C.) What the error code means
D.) If there is something completely left field that I'm missing here?

```
Imports PdfSharp
Imports PdfSharp.Drawing
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1

    Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)

        Dim eventlog As System.IO.StreamWriter
        eventlog = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("\\csimccs01\FTP\Out\PDFCREATOR\log.txt", True)

        eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Process Started at")

        Dim countargs = 0
        Dim FY As String = ""
        Dim FP As String = ""
        Dim con1 As New SqlConnection
        Dim con2 As New SqlConnection
        Dim con3 As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
        Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
        Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand

        Dim sqldataset2 As SqlDataReader
        Dim packid As Integer
        Dim LV7Symbol As String
        Dim PackDescription As String
        Dim SPPATH As String
        Dim RptVer As Integer
        Dim outputdoc As PdfDocument
        Dim PDFCount As Integer
        Dim progress As Integer = 0
        Dim importdoc As PdfDocument
        Dim count As Integer


        Dim constr As String
        Dim inputfilefolder As String
        Dim outputfilefolder As String
        Dim fullinputfilepath As String
        Dim outputfilename As String

        eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Looking for config file")
        Try
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("\\csimccs01\FTP\Out\PDFCREATOR\config.xml") Then
                Dim xmlconfig = XDocument.Load("\\csimccs01\FTP\Out\PDFCREATOR\config.xml")
                constr = xmlconfig.<config>.<DBCONNECTIONSTRING>.Value
                inputfilefolder = xmlconfig.<config>.<FilePath>.<Input>.Value
                outputfilefolder = xmlconfig.<config>.<FilePath>.<Output>.Value
                eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Config file loaded and variables set")
                eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " inputfolder: " & inputfilefolder)
                eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " outputfolder: " & outputfilefolder)
            Else
                eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Config File Not Found")
                Exit Sub
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(1)
            eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Config File Not Found, routine exited by exception")
            eventlog.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        countargs = 0

        eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Setting Fiscal Year & Period Variables")

        If FY = "" Then

            FY = "FY2016"
        End If

        If FP = "" Then

            FP = "FP01"
        End If
        eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Fiscal Year & Period Variables set")

        Try
            eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Attempting to open database con1")
            con1.ConnectionString = constr
            con1.Open()
            eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Con1 open")
            cmd1.Connection = con1
            cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT [PackID],[LV7Symbol],[LV7Description],[SharePoint_Output_Path],[Report_Version] FROM [D_EXP_CPM].[dbo].[FACT_REPORT_CONTROL_TABLE]"
            Dim sqldataset1 As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
            eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Report List loaded into Dataset1")


            eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Starting to loop through Dataset1")

            While sqldataset1.Read()


                packid = sqldataset1.Item("PackID")
                LV7Symbol = sqldataset1.Item("LV7Symbol").ToString
                PackDescription = sqldataset1.Item("LV7Description").ToString
                SPPATH = sqldataset1.Item("SharePoint_Output_Path").ToString
                RptVer = sqldataset1.Item("Report_Version") + 1
                eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Pack level variables set for pack id " & packid)
                eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Opening connection3 to update version number")
                con3.ConnectionString = constr
                con3.Open()
                cmd3.Connection = con3
                cmd3.CommandText = "UPDATE [D_EXP_CPM].[dbo].[FACT_REPORT_CONTROL_TABLE] SET [Report_Version]=" & RptVer & " WHERE [PackID] =" & packid
                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con3.Close()
                eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Version Updated")
                eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Connection 3 closed")


                Try
                    eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Opening connection2")

                    con2.ConnectionString = constr
                    con2.Open()
                    cmd2.Connection = con2
                    cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT [EntryID],[PackID], [TemplateID], [SortOrder] FROM [D_EXP_CPM].[dbo].[FACT_REPORTPACK_PAGE_CONFIG] WHERE [PACKID] = " & packid & "  Order By [PackID], [SortOrder]"
                    sqldataset2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
                    eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Results or pack page configuration loaded into sqldatset2")

                    eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Opening temporary PDF")
                    outputdoc = New PdfDocument
                    eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Starting to loop through Pack pages for pack " & packid)
                    While sqldataset2.Read()

                        If Not sqldataset2.HasRows Then
                            eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " No template configuration data found for packid " & packid)
                            GoTo nextrpt
                        End If

                        fullinputfilepath = inputfilefolder & "\CC " & LV7Symbol & "_TID" & (sqldataset2.Item("TemplateID") - 1) & "_" & FP & "_" & FY & ".pdf"
                        eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " input file path set to: " & fullinputfilepath)

                        Try
                            eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " attempting to read input file")
                            importdoc = PdfReader.Open(fullinputfilepath, PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)
                            eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " inputfile read successfully")
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Unable to read intput file, move to next report")
                            GoTo nextrpt 
                        End Try

                        count = importdoc.PageCount

                        progress = 0

                        Do Until progress = count
                            Dim pdfpage As PdfPage = importdoc.Pages(progress)
                            outputdoc.AddPage(pdfpage)
                            progress = progress + 1
                        Loop
                        eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " incrementing pdf page count")
                        PDFCount = PDFCount + 1
                    End While
                    eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " all pages of input file consolidated")

                    PackDescription.Replace("&", "and")
                    eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " '&' charcter removed from file names")

                    outputfilename = outputfilefolder & "\" & LV7Symbol & "_" & FY & "_" & FP & "_" & PackDescription & "_VER" & RptVer & ".pdf"

                    eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " attempting to save output PDF as: " & outputfilename)

                    If outputdoc.PageCount > 0 Then
                        outputdoc.Save(outputfilename)
                    End If

                    eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " output file saved")
nextrpt:

                Catch ex As Exception
                    eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Exception encountered in page level try catch")
                Finally
                    con2.Close()
                    eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Connection 2 closed")

                End Try


            End While



        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(1)
            eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Exception encountered in report level try catch")
            eventlog.Close()
            Exit Sub
        Finally
            con1.Close()
            eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Connection 1 closed")
        End Try

        Console.WriteLine(0)
        eventlog.WriteLine(Now() & " Process completed successfully")
        eventlog.Close()

        Exit Sub



    End Sub


End Module
```

Comment: Did you really need to include all those comment lines? Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Comments removed. - I think the issue may be something to do with the .net version installed on the server too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't the code but the .net version installed on the server. Wasn't able to upgrade .net so changed the compile settings in visual studio to .net 4 and amended the package file to target net40 instead of net45 and this now works.